# Unable to get saved queries through PHP

Tags: php, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I am having issues retrieving a saved query with the ReportService.getSavedQueriesByStatement.
Report type : Historical
I need to fetch "Total CPM, CPC, CPD, and vCPM revenue"

```
$statementBuilder = (new StatementBuilder())->where('id = :id')
        ->orderBy('id ASC')
        ->limit(1)
        ->withBindVariableValue('id', $savedQueryId);

$savedQueryPage = $reportService->getSavedQueriesByStatement(
        $statementBuilder->toStatement()
    );
```

Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The saved query is not compatible with this API version.

Answer (score 0):

Check that all fields you have in the saved query are compatible with the API.
Most likely it's an issue with your date range since those differer in the UI and the API, try selecting "Yesterday" as date range and see if it works better.

From the FAQ:
https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reporting

> **Why isn't my saved query compatible with the API?**
>
> Certain reporting features aren't available in the API. This includes
>   columns, dimension attributes, dimensions, and date range types. For
>   incompatible date range types, you can save the query with a supported
>   type to make it retrievable, then alter the query to meet your desired
>   fixed date range.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

1. Donot copy of another query IN GAM, create with New query
2. Date Range use Fixed.